# python subprocess check output: how to get the entire message

Tags: python, hadoop, subprocess

i'm using subprocess.check_output to delete folders in hadoop and would like to be able to get the same results as if i execute the hadoop command from console.

So, it can happen that i try to delete multiple directories of which some do not exists.

This command fails entirely (because my 'nonexisting' directory can't be found)

```
subprocess.check_output('hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash my_host/path_to_existing_directory my_host/path_to_nonexisting_directory', shell = True)
```

To prevent a failure i can do:

```
try:
    subprocess.check_output('hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash  my_host/path_to_existing_directory/ my_host/path_to_nonexisting_directory', shell = True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output, 'some of the folders were not found')
```

This second option is better as it tells me which of my directories were deleted if any. And to distinguish that some were not, i can add the 'some of the folders were not found' into my printout.

However, when i execute the same command from commandline, i get better information, which i would like to replicate:

```
hadoop fs -rm -r -skipTrash  my_host/path_to_existing_directory/ my_host/path_to_nonexisting_directory
```

Returns:

```
Deleted my_host/path_to_existing_directory
rm: `my_host/path_to_nonexisting_directory': no such file or directory
```

Comment: It is better to use `subprocess.popen`  for executing shell functions

Comment: Fair enough, but i still don't know how to get the proper output :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The process may write error messages to the *standard **error** stream* `stderr`, which you can also capture by redirecting it to the standard output `stdout` using using the parameter `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT`

So, your code will look like this:

```
try:
    output = subprocess.check_output('...', shell = True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(e.output, 'some of the folders were not found')
```

Comment: Wow, that is super simple! Thank you :)